# List of fonts that are pre-avaliable on gd

Tags: php, gd

Can anyone tell me the name of all fonts which are pre-avaliable with gd library, that means I do **not** have to use a `imagettftext` or `imageloadfont`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple 8x8 bitmap font is compiled into GD. There's nothing beyond that AFAIK.